# Protoc file not found error when trying to import proto file from different directory

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

Unable to figure out why I'm getting a file not found error when I'm running a protoc command to generate the relevant go files.

Problem: Trying to figure out what the appropriate protoc command is while trying to import a proto file from a different directory.
I've set my proto-path in GoLand to be `~/go-workspace/github.com/xyz/project/internal`

Structure

```
project
  - internal  
    - song
      - proto 
        - *.proto 
    - search
      - proto 
        - *.proto
```

Song.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";
package song;

option go_package = "github.com/xyz/project/internal/song/proto";
......
```

Search.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";
package search;

option go_package = "github.com/xyz/project/internal/search/proto";

import "song/proto/song.proto";
```

Makefile:

```
generate:
     protoc --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative \
         --go-grpc_out=. --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative \
         proto/*.proto
```

Error:

```
song/proto/song.proto: File not found.
proto/search.proto:6:1: Import "song/proto/song.proto" was not found or had errors.
proto/search.proto:16:12: "song.Song" is not defined.
proto/search.proto:20:12: "song.Artist" is not defined.
```

Comment: Try adding `--proto_path=..` to the `protoc` command line. This tells protoc where to look for imports and to find `song/proto/song.proto` the starting point needs to be `internal`. More info in [the doce](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#generating)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in a comment, you could use the `--proto_path` or `-I` option with the protoc compiler and you need to start your import with internal.

Another solution that I can see and that would not require multiple Makefiles, is putting the following Makefile at the project level:

```
generate:
    protoc --go_out=. \
    --go_opt=module=github.com/xyz/project \
    internal/search/proto/*.proto \
    internal/song/proto/*.proto
```

Note the the `--go_opt=module` that will trim your package name and help you generate the protobuf code inside the respective proto directories and note that I'm passing the entire paths to the proto directories.

and then search.proto like:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

package search;

option go_package = "github.com/xyz/project/internal/search/proto";

import "internal/song/proto/song.proto";
```